Can one legally add effective watermarks in CC BY-SA texts?
Assume some text (plain text) is licensed under CC BY-SA and someone wants to add a watermark in that text. Would they have clearly identify the watermark (thereby defeating the point of the watermark) to respect the attribution requirement? More generally, can one legally add effective watermarks in CC BY-SA texts? (effective=non obvious)

How would you technically add watermarks to a text in a non-obvious way? Something like a digital signature would be very obvious and can (legally!) just be removed if the text is under a CC license.

@PMF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking

I've inadvertently check to close as RSLA. This should instead be closed because it's not a question about the law.

@bdb484 meant to explore the legal side of it, eg respecting attribution requirement

@Sneftel Such a watermark isn't in the text, though. It's attached to it. (unlike with images)

@PMF can add watermark by amending text

@PMF There are steganographic techniques to hide messages in text as well as in images.

The Attribution requirements don't require you to identify changes, only to indicate if there are changes. It may be good practice to indicate more details about the changes, but it's not a requirement.
This is less of a legal question, but more of a practical question. Part of the Attribution requirement is "a URI or hyperlink to the Licensed Material to the extent reasonably practical". As long as the upstream works are available, you can trace back and see differences between the (potentially watermarked derivative work) distribution that you have and the original, even opting to use the original content over the derivative work.


can one legally add effective watermarks in CC BY-SA texts?

An author can embed whatever they'd like in a work that they create, including in derived works.
However, if the author shares it under a licence that allows modifications (like a CC BY-SA licence) the watermark can be removed in later derivative works.

Legally...
You can add the watermark, but you earn nothing from it: you still have to link the original, and if all you did was add the watermark, you only gain the chance to track whoever got a distribution from you.
Practically...
You need a format like epub or PDF or other that actually supports some sort of watermarking. However, that watermark is gone the moment someone recompiles the whole text (such as by copying it into LaTeX or into plain txt), making "they worked on  my distribution" untraceable.
